# Unable to install npm packages: browser-sync

Tags: node.js, npm

i am getting tunneling socket error while installing browser-sync module,i'm behind a corporate proxy..

```html
npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/rase-/node-XMLHttpRequest/archive/a6b6f
2.tar.gz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could
not be established, cause=Parse Error
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure NPM to be able to use it from behind a corporate proxy. You can do this easily by running 2 commands in the terminal replacing the domain and port with the ones for your company network -

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

Comment: did you change the domain and port to mirror the ones provided by your company?